# How to configure timeout of JedisConnectionFactory based on Spring Boot framework?

Tags: redis, timeout, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and I'm confused how to configure the timeout to connect Redis.

Currently, my configurations are:

*application.yml*:

```yaml
spring.redis.host: myhost
spring.redis.port: 6379
spring.redis.pool.max-idle: 8
spring.redis.pool.min-idle: 0
spring.redis.pool.max-active: 8
spring.redis.pool.max-wait: -1
```

*StringRedisDao.java*:

```java
@Autowired
public StringRedisDao(final StringRedisTemplate template, final ObjectMapper mapper) {
    if (template.getConnectionFactory() instanceof JedisConnectionFactory) {
        ((JedisConnectionFactory) template.getConnectionFactory()).getShardInfo().setTimeout(5000);
        ((JedisConnectionFactory) template.getConnectionFactory()).setTimeout(5000);
    }
    this.template = template;
    this.mapper = mapper;
}
```

I use Wireshark to capture the packets and I found that the Redis was disconnected after 2 seconds, not 5 seconds as I set in the code above.

Because of this, I cannot perform a requests that the query time of Redis is more than 2 seconds.

Please, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

There is also a configuration setting you can put in [*application.properties*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.redis.timeout):

```
spring.redis.timeout=5000
```

Comment: Really? Have you confirmed that this actually has an effect?
I cannot see any timeout property in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.redis.RedisProperties!

Comment: Here is a list of common properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: ... and that property is not in the list .. maybe it was in the past

Comment: @Rafael AFAIK there is not master list of all available properties. The list of common properties in that link is not comprehensive, however it does look like the property has changed to utilize the "spring.data.redis" prefix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisProperties.java

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to someone.
I have used [Redisson](https://redisson.org/) client for redis implementation. Setting timeout for redis use `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=5000`