# How to set Redis client read timeout in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

I have a Spring Boot Redis client and constantly hit *read timeout* when I have to delete a large date set.

The Redis client configuration *read-timeout* is set to 2 seconds by default.

I can only get the *read timeout* setting, but no way to set it.
Not able to find any documentation on how to set it in the `application.properties` either.

```
JedisConnectionFactory jfact = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
Duration duration = jfact.getClientConfiguration().getReadTimeout();
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439378/how-to-configure-timeout-of-jedisconnectionfactory-base-on-spring-boot-framework

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `JedisClientConfiguration` builder to configure and use `JedisConnectionFactory` constructor that takes in `JedisClientConfiguration` as shown below:

```java
Duration readTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(30 * 1000);
Duration connectTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(3 * 1000);
JedisClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder()
        .readTimeout(readTimeout)
        .connectTimeout(connectTimeout)
        .usePooling()
        .build();

JedisConnectionFactory jfact = new JedisConnectionFactory(
        redisStandaloneConfiguration,
        clientConfiguration
);
```